# Crear servidor (SQL Server Management 2008)

Tags: sql, servidor, instalacion

Acabo de instalar el SQL Server Management 2008, al momento de crear un servidor (con autentificación windows) e intentar conectarme tengo el siguiente error:
[image: error]

en la lista de servidores registrados no puedo iniciar o activar el servidor creado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el administrador de SQL, no hay elementos para actualizar o activar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual podría ser el error?

Answer (score 1):

Sigue todos los pasos del [documento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017):

> Recopilación de información sobre la instancia de SQL Server

En primer lugar, debe recopilar información básica sobre el motor de base de datos.

1. Confirme que la instancia del motor de base de datos de SQL Server
   está instalada y en ejecución.

   Inicie sesión en el equipo que hospeda la instancia de SQL Server.
   Inicie el Administrador de configuración de SQL Server. (El Administrador de configuración se instala automáticamente en el equipo al instalar SQL Server. Las instrucciones para iniciar el Administrador de configuración varían ligeramente según la versión de SQL Server y Windows. Para obtener ayuda para iniciar el Administrador de configuración, vea Administrador de configuración de SQL Server).
   En el panel izquierdo del Administrador de configuración, seleccione Servicios de SQL Server. En el panel derecho, confirme que la instancia del motor de base de datos está presente y en ejecución. Una instancia denominada SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) es una instancia predeterminada (sin nombre). Solo puede haber una instancia predeterminada. Los nombres de otras instancias (con nombre) aparecerán en la lista entre paréntesis. SQL Server Express usa el nombre SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) como nombre de instancia, a menos que alguien le diera otra denominación durante la instalación. Anote el nombre de la instancia a la que está intentando conectarse. Además, confirme que la instancia se está ejecutando. Para ello, busque la flecha verde. Si la instancia tiene un cuadrado rojo, haga clic en ella con el botón derecho y luego haga clic en Iniciar. Debería volverse verde.
       Si está intentando conectarse a una instancia con nombre, asegúrese de que se esté ejecutando el servicio SQL Server Browser.
2. Obtenga la dirección IP del equipo.

   En el menú Iniciar, haga clic en Ejecutar. En la ventana Ejecutar , escriba cmdy haga clic en Aceptar.
   En la ventana del símbolo del sistema, escriba ipconfig y pulse ENTRAR. Anote la dirección IPv4 y la dirección IPv6 . (SQL Server puede conectarse mediante el protocolo IP versión 4 anterior o el protocolo IP versión 6 más reciente. La red podría permitir uno o ambos. La mayoría de los usuarios comienza por solucionar los problemas de la dirección IPv4 . Es más corta y más fácil de escribir).
3. Obtenga el número de puerto TCP usado por SQL Server. En la mayoría
   de los casos la conexión al motor de base de datos se realiza desde
   otro equipo mediante el protocolo TCP.

   Con SQL Server Management Studio en el equipo que ejecuta SQL Server, conéctese a la instancia de SQL Server. En el Explorador de objetos, expanda Administración, Registros de SQL Servery luego haga doble clic en el registro actual.
   En el Visor de registros, haga clic en el botón Filtrar de la barra de herramientas. En el cuadro El mensaje contiene texto , escriba El servidor está escuchando en, haga clic en Aplicar filtroy luego en Aceptar.
   Debería aparecer un mensaje similar a El servidor está escuchando en [ 'any'  1433]. Este mensaje indica que esta instancia de SQL Server está escuchando en todas las direcciones IP de este equipo (para IP versión 4) y está escuchando al puerto TCP 1433. (El puerto TCP 1433 suele ser el que usa el motor de base de datos. Solo una instancia de SQL Server puede usar un puerto, por lo que si hay más de una instancia de SQL Server instalada, algunas instancias deben usar otros números de puerto). Anote el número de puerto usado por la instancia de SQL Server a la que está intentando conectarse.

---

> Habilitar protocolos

En algunas instalaciones de SQL Server, no se puede conectar al motor de base de datos desde otro equipo a menos que un administrador use el Administrador de configuración para permitirlo. Para habilitar conexiones desde otro equipo:

1. Abra el Administrador de configuración de SQL Server como se explicó
   anteriormente.
2. En el panel izquierdo del Administrador de configuración, expanda
   Configuración de red de SQL Servery luego seleccione la instancia de
   SQL Server a la que quiere conectarse. El panel derecho muestra los
   protocolos de conexión disponibles. Normalmente la memoria
   compartida está habilitada. Solo se puede usar desde el mismo
   equipo, por lo que en la mayoría de las instalaciones se deja
   habilitada. Para conectarse a SQL Server desde otro equipo,
   normalmente se usa TCP/IP. Si TCP/IP no está habilitado, haga clic
   con el botón derecho en TCP/IPy luego haga clic en Habilitar.
3. Si modificó la configuración habilitada de cualquier protocolo, debe
   reiniciar el motor de base de datos. En el panel izquierdo,
   seleccione Servicios de SQL Server. En el panel derecho, haga clic
   con el botón derecho en la instancia del motor de base de datos y
   luego haga clic en Reiniciar.

> Prueba de la conectividad TCP/IP

La conexión a SQL Server mediante TCP/IP exige que Windows pueda establecerla. Use la herramienta ping para probar TCP.

1. En el menú Iniciar, haga clic en Ejecutar. En la ventana Ejecutar ,
   escriba cmdy haga clic en Aceptar.
2. En la ventana del símbolo del sistema, escriba ping y luego la
   dirección IP del equipo con SQL Server. Por ejemplo, ping
   192.168.1.101 con una dirección IPv4 o ping fe80::d51d:5ab5:6f09:8f48%11 con una dirección IPv6. (Debe
   reemplazar los números después de hacer ping con las direcciones IP
   que recopiló anteriormente en el equipo).
3. Si la red está configurada correctamente, recibirá una respuesta
   como Respuesta desde  seguida de alguna información
   adicional. Si recibe un error como Host de destino inaccesible o
   Tiempo de espera agotado para la solicitud, significa que TCP/IP no
   está configurado correctamente. (Compruebe que la dirección IP es
   correcta y que se escribió correctamente). Los errores en este punto
   podrían indicar un problema con el equipo cliente, el equipo
   servidor o algo relacionado con la red, como un enrutador. Internet
   cuenta con muchos recursos para solucionar problemas de TCP/IP. Un
   buen lugar para comenzar es este artículo de 2006: How to
   Troubleshoot Basic TCP/IP Problems (Cómo solucionar problemas
   básicos de TCP/IP).
4. Después, si la prueba de ping mediante la dirección IP fue correcta,
   compruebe que el nombre del equipo se pueda resolver en la dirección
   TCP/IP. En el equipo cliente, en la ventana del símbolo del sistema,
   escriba ping y luego el nombre del equipo con SQL Server. Por
   ejemplo, ping newofficepc
5. Si pudiera hacer ping a la dirección IP, pero recibe ahora un error
   como Host de destino inaccesible. o Tiempo de espera agotado para la
   solicitud, es posible que tenga información antigua de resolución de
   nombres (obsoleta) almacenada en caché en el equipo cliente. Escriba
   ipconfig /flushdns para borrar la caché DNS (resolución de nombres
   dinámica). Luego vuelva a hacer ping al equipo por nombre. Con la
   caché DNS vacía, el equipo cliente buscará la información más
   reciente sobre la dirección IP del equipo servidor.
6. Si la red está configurada correctamente, recibirá una respuesta
   como Respuesta desde  seguida de alguna información
   adicional. Si puede hacer ping correctamente al equipo servidor por
   dirección IP pero recibe un error como Host de destino inaccesible o
   Tiempo de espera agotado para la solicitud al hacer ping por nombre
   de equipo, la resolución de nombres no está configurada
   correctamente. (Para obtener más información, vea el artículo de
   2006 mencionado anteriormente: How to Troubleshoot Basic TCP/IP
   Problems [Cómo solucionar problemas básicos de TCP/IP]). La
   resolución de nombres correcta no es necesaria para conectarse a SQL
   Server, pero si no se puede resolver el nombre del equipo en una
   dirección IP, se debe especificar la dirección IP para realizar las
   conexiones. No es una situación ideal, pero la resolución de nombres
   se puede arreglar más adelante.

> Prueba de una conexión local

Antes de solucionar un problema de conexión desde otro equipo, pruebe la capacidad de conectarse desde una aplicación cliente instalada en el equipo con SQL Server. (Esto evitará problemas de firewall). En este procedimiento se usa SQL Server Management Studio. Si no tiene instalado Management Studio, consulte Descarga de SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). (Si no puede instalar Management Studio, puede probar la conexión con la utilidad sqlcmd.exe que se instala con el motor de base de datos. Para obtener información sobre sqlcmd.exe, vea sqlcmd (utilidad)).

1. Inicie sesión en el equipo donde está instalado SQL Server con un
   inicio de sesión que tenga permiso para acceder a SQL Server.
   (Durante la instalación, SQL Server necesita que se especifique al
   menos un inicio de sesión como administrador de SQL Server. Si no
   conoce ningún administrador, consulte Conectarse a SQL Server cuando
   los administradores del sistema no tienen acceso).
2. En la página Iniciar, escriba SQL Server Management Studio, o bien,
   en el menú Inicio de versiones anteriores de Windows, seleccione
   Todos los programas, Microsoft SQL Servery luego haga clic en SQL
   Server Management Studio.
3. En el cuadro de diálogo Conectar con el servidor , en el cuadro de
   tipo Servidor , seleccione Motor de base de datos. En el cuadro
   Autenticación , seleccione Autenticación de Windows. En el cuadro
   Nombre del servidor , escriba una de las siguientes opciones:

[image: Prueba conexión local]

> Apertura de un puerto del firewall

Desde hace ya muchos años, a partir de Windows XP Service Pack 2, Firewall de Windows está activado y bloquea las conexiones desde otros equipos. Para conectar con TCP/IP desde otro equipo, tiene que configurar el firewall en el equipo de SQL Server de modo que permita las conexiones al puerto TCP usado por el motor de base de datos. Como se mencionó anteriormente, la instancia predeterminada suele escuchar en el puerto TCP 1433. Si tiene instancias con nombre o ha cambiado el valor predeterminado, es posible que el puerto TCP SQL Server escuche en otro puerto. Consulte la sección inicial sobre cómo recopilar la información para determinar el puerto.
Si se conecta a una instancia con nombre o a un puerto distinto al puerto TCP 1433, también debe abrir el puerto UDP 1434 del servicio SQL Server Browser. Para obtener instrucciones paso a paso sobre la apertura de un puerto de Firewall de Windows, consulte Configurar Firewall de Windows para el acceso al motor de base de datos.

> Prueba de la conexión

Una vez que se pueda conectar con TCP en el mismo equipo, es hora de intentar conectar desde el equipo cliente. En teoría, podría usar cualquier aplicación cliente, pero para evitar más complejidad, instale las herramientas de administración de SQL Server en el cliente y realice el intento con SQL Server Management Studio.

1. En el equipo cliente, con SQL Server Management Studio, intente
   conectarse mediante la dirección IP y el número de puerto TCP en el
   formato dirección IP coma número de puerto. Por ejemplo,
   192.168.1.101,1433 ; si esto no funciona, es probable que tenga uno de los siguientes problemas:

   - Elping de la dirección IP no funciona, lo que indica un problema de
     configuración general de TCP. Vuelva a la sección Prueba de la
     conectividad TCP/IP.
   - SQL Server no está escuchando en el protocolo TCP. Vuelva a la
     sección Habilitar protocolos.
   - SQL Server está escuchando en un puerto distinto al especificado.
     Vuelva a la sección Recopilación de información sobre la instancia de
     SQL Server.
   - El firewall está bloqueando el puerto TCP de SQL Server. Vuelva a la
     sección Apertura de un puerto del firewall.
2. Una vez que se pueda conectar con el número de puerto y la dirección
   IP, intente conectarse con la dirección IP y sin número de puerto.
   En el caso de una instancia predeterminada, use solo la dirección
   IP. En el caso de una instancia con nombre, use la dirección IP y el
   nombre de instancia en el formato dirección IP barra diagonal
   inversa nombre de instancia, por ejemplo, 192.168.1.101\PAYROLL ; si
   esto no funciona, es probable que tenga uno de los siguientes
   problemas:

   - Si se conecta a la instancia predeterminada, podría estar escuchando
     en un puerto distinto al puerto TCP 1433 y el cliente no estaría
     intentando conectarse al número de puerto correcto.
   - Si se conecta a una instancia con nombre, el número de puerto no se
     devuelve al cliente.

Ambos problemas están relacionados con el servicio SQL Server Browser, que proporciona el número de puerto al cliente. Las soluciones son:

- Inicie el servicio SQL Server Browser. Vuelva a la sección 1.d de
  Recopilación de información sobre la instancia de SQL Server.
- El firewall está bloqueando el servicio SQL Server Browser. Abra el
  puerto UDP 1434 del firewall. Vuelva a la sección Apertura de un
  puerto del firewall. (Asegúrese de estar abriendo un puerto UDP, no
  un puerto TCP. Son cosas diferentes).
- Un enrutador está bloqueando la información del puerto UDP 1434. La
  comunicación UDP (protocolo de datagramas de usuario) no está
  diseñada para pasar a través de enrutadores. Esto evita que la red se
  llene de tráfico de baja prioridad. Es posible que pueda configurar
  el enrutador para reenviar el tráfico UDP. También puede optar por
  proporcionar siempre el número de puerto al conectarse.
- Si el equipo cliente usa Windows 7 o Windows Server 2008 (o un
  sistema operativo más reciente), el sistema operativo cliente podría
  eliminar el tráfico UDP porque la respuesta del servidor se devuelve
  desde una dirección IP diferente a la que se consultó. Esta es una
  característica de seguridad que bloquea la "asignación de origen no
  estricta". Para obtener más información, consulte la sección Varias
  direcciones IP de servidor del tema de los Libros en pantalla
  Solucionar problemas de tiempo de espera expirado. Se trata de un
  artículo de SQL Server 2008 R2, pero las entidades de seguridad aún
  son válidas. Es posible que pueda configurar el cliente para usar la
  dirección IP correcta. También puede optar por proporcionar siempre
  el número de puerto al conectarse.

  1. Una vez que se pueda conectar con la dirección IP (o la dirección IP
     y el nombre de instancia de una instancia con nombre), intente
     conectarse con el nombre de equipo (o el nombre de equipo y el
     nombre de instancia de una instancia con nombre). Coloque tcp:
     delante del nombre del equipo para forzar una conexión TCP/IP. Por
     ejemplo, en el caso de la instancia predeterminada en un equipo
     denominado ACCNT27, use tcp:ACCNT27 ; en el caso de una instancia
     con nombre denominada PAYROLLen ese equipo, use tcp:ACCNT27\PAYROLL
     . Si puede conectarse con la dirección IP pero no con el nombre de
     equipo, entonces tiene un problema de resolución de nombres. Vuelva
     a la sección 4 de Prueba de la conectividad TCP/IP.
  2. Una vez que se conecte mediante el nombre de equipo al forzar TCP,
     intente conectarse con el nombre de equipo pero sin forzar TCP. Por
     ejemplo, en el caso de una instancia predeterminada, use solo el
     nombre de equipo como CCNT27 ; en el caso de una instancia con
     nombre, use el nombre de equipo y el nombre de instancia como
     ACCNT27\PAYROLL . Si puede conectarse al forzar TCP, pero no sin
     hacerlo, es probable que el cliente esté usando otro protocolo (por
     ejemplo, canalizaciones con nombre).
- En el equipo cliente, en el panel izquierdo del Administrador de
  configuración de SQL Server, expanda Configuración version
  Configuration, and then select Client Protocols.
- En el panel derecho, asegúrese de que TCP/IP esté habilitado. Si
  TCP/IP está deshabilitado, haga clic con el botón derecho en TCP/IP y
  luego haga clic en Habilitar.
- Asegúrese de que el orden de protocolo de TCP/IP sea un número menor
  que el de los protocolos de canalizaciones con nombre (o VIA en
  versiones anteriores). Por lo general, debería dejar la memoria
  compartida como orden 1 y TCP/IP como orden 2. La memoria compartida
  solo se usa cuando el cliente y SQL Server se están ejecutando en el
  mismo equipo. Todos los protocolos habilitados se prueban por orden
  hasta que se establece la conexión, aunque la memoria compartida se
  omite cuando la conexión no está en el mismo equipo.